# Bim360 Deleted files and versions

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have issues using bim360 Api. I would like to hide all files and versions which are deleted, but the problem is that I cannot find any similarities between the deleted ones and the others, just the name. I tried to include "hidden" filter in my query ($"projects/b.{projectId}/folders/{folderId}/contents") , but here is another problem, the deleted file comes with an attribute hidden and its extension type "document" and an item with extension type "file" which doesn't seem to have a link to the hidden document. Both of them have nothing in common except the name.
The versions come with same issues, if I delete a file in bim360 docs, when I make a request to bimApi with this query: $"projects/b.{projectId}/items/{id}/versions", I receive 2 different versions of the same file but with different bodies except the name, also the deleted one comes with extension type "versions:autodesk.core:Deleted". How can I figure out what is the resemblance between them, or the only thing that I could do is to compare by name, because I know that the name is unique?

Answer (score 0):

The filter is supported to get deleted files only. e.g.
[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/{{project_id_dm}}/folders/{{one_folder_urn}}/contents?filter[hidden]=true](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%7B%7Bproject_id_dm%7D%7D/folders/%7B%7Bone_folder_urn%7D%7D/contents?filter%5Bhidden%5D=true)

In the API help document, more filters are available:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/filtering/

Comment: @cvo31, I am not sure the downvote is from you, or from Dharman.  If from you, could you update further my answer is not helpful nor not?  Dharman helped me to polish the description.  Thank you both

Comment: hello, it's not from me, thank you for the answer but even if I filter with false I still receive the deleted files. The hidden true just shows me the document which is deleted but the file still comes with hidden false

Comment: @cvo31,  sorry for late response. I double tested with my folder in BIM360, it looks it works well with this flag. When it is true, only deleted files are returned. When it is false, only un-deleted files are returned. We may setup a meeting to check remotely. Could you send me an private email at xiaodong.liang AT autodesk.com?